# Suspicious Partial Dependence Curves from a Random Forest Model

Tags: r, classification, random-forest, partial-dependency-plots

I have created several Partial Dependence Plots (PDP) for some of the top variables in my RF model. Overall, the plots seem to make sense; however, for the 'Bog" class, the probability for all variables analyzed goes up to around 0.9 probability, while for the other variables, the probability is significantly less (e.g. 0.02).

I understand that the probability will change depending on the class, and a predictor variable may have more importance in one class than another. However, the high probability for all bog classes has me questioning the data. I would appreciate any feedback and ideas on troubleshooting approaches (if necessary).
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you exclude that class from your RF, and then re-train it, how does the validation score change?

Comment: @EngrStudent, it dropped like 0.3% so is around 92% OA.

Comment: This suggests that the overall learning is not compromised by that label.  0.3% of 92% can be run-to-run training variation.  If you reran it 100 times with different seeds, you might easily get that.   I was initially thinking you might have something that allows the learner to "index" (basically create a false-hash) so it looks like it has near perfect learning, but it is just memorizing and has terrible generalization.

Comment: I only ran the model twice. I found out what I did wrong. I was having issues making PDPs for each class, so I created subsets of my data per class from the rf model and then made the PDPs. This explains why I had funky results. I rewrote my script and used the which,class argument and got the results I desired and what makes sense. Thanks  for your input!

Comment: So write up a clean if brief and effective answer for posterity.